# php syntax on ateInterval::createfromDateString

Tags: php

I'm having a problem wtih some syntax in that I'm trying to amend repinterval so that it takes the value from my repetition variable.  Everything I try doesn't work.

```
$repetition = 3;
$repinterval = DateInterval::createfromDateString('".$repetition." weeks');
```

Can anyone see where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `'".$repetition." weeks'` results in a string containing `".$repetition." weeks`.

There are multiple ways to form a string, here are two:

```
printf("$repetition weeks");
printf(PHP_EOL);
printf($repetition.' weeks');
```

The top and bottom lines both print `3 weeks`.

So, one option would be to change your code to:

```
DateInterval::createfromDateString($repetition.' weeks');
```

Check out the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) on strings for details.

Comment: Thanks for the help Spooky.  Working well now.